# How to put a Worpdpress theme in spanish (having the po file)?

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-eleven, language, translation

I am building a Wordpress blog system in Spanish and I'd like to have the default theme also translated to "es_ES". I am already running this Wordpress installation in Spanish. What I'd like to know is how to do the same with the default theme (twenty-eleven).

This site allows us to download the po file with the translation: http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.2.x/twentyeleven/es/default

But I don't know what to do next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a **es_ES.mo** file, using the .po file included with the Theme. Try using something like [POEdit](http://poedit.net) or a similar utility.

Comment: That's right, but, what then? I'd like to know the process. For I have downloaded the PO and MO files from http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.2.x/twentyeleven/es/default and then uploaded them to domain.com/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/languages however no change occurred...

Comment: What is the language setting for WordPress installed on domain.com?

Comment: es_CL but it could be any other language.

Comment: Well, if WordPress is using es_CL, wouldn't it be logical that it would *not* use es_ES from the Theme? Try providing a es_CL.mo for the Theme, or changing WordPress to es_ES?

Comment: I used es_ES as an example. I did not noticed. Sorry for the confusion. This post helped me to get through: http://urbangiraffe.com/articles/translating-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/